# how to Parse Soap Response in Java

Tags: java, xml, soap-client

The following is the Soap Response i am getting but i dont know 
how to parse the Soap response.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://localhost/plaza/api" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns1:requestResponse>
        <return xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Struct">
            <last_dir_trans xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Struct">
                <p_liveid xsi:type="xsd:string">124</p_liveid>
                <p_amount xsi:type="xsd:string">20</p_amount>
                <p_dateadded xsi:type="xsd:string">2016-08-15 07:37:21</p_dateadded>
            </last_dir_trans>
            <last_knet_trans xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Struct">
                <p_knetsuc_id xsi:type="xsd:string">3</p_knetsuc_id>
                <p_amount xsi:type="xsd:string">20</p_amount>
                <p_dateadded xsi:type="xsd:string">2016-09-22 15:33:56</p_dateadded>
            </last_knet_trans>
            <last_user xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Struct">
                <s_subid xsi:type="xsd:string">23223</s_subid>
                <s_name xsi:type="xsd:string">test1</s_name>
                <s_address xsi:type="xsd:string"></s_address>
                <s_phonenumber xsi:type="xsd:string">96566565656</s_phonenumber>
                <s_civilid xsi:type="xsd:string">2016-08-15 07:3</s_civilid>
                <s_total_payable xsi:type="xsd:string">240</s_total_payable>
                <s_monthly xsi:type="xsd:string">20</s_monthly>
                <s_email xsi:type="xsd:string"></s_email>
                <s_dateadded xsi:type="xsd:string">0000-00-00 00:00:00</s_dateadded>
            </last_user>
        </return>
    </ns1:requestResponse>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
```

I want to parse the above code in java.thanks in advance

Comment: Use a SOAP library such as that [built into the JDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/jax-ws-2-141894.html), [Project Kenai](http://jax-ws.java.net/), [Apache Axis](http://axis.apache.org/axis/), etc.

Comment: hi @manish i am unable to get from the link can you pleas suggest me an example